# database polling osb service

Tags: database, osb

OSB 12c Database polling service was working fine until it suddenly stopped polling. Data source and connection factory config settings were correct and Data source testing returned success in console. when the server was restarted, the service started polling fine. 
Going forward, I would like to get a notification if and when my DB poller service stops polling. I appreciate any long term or short term approaches to solve this issue.

Comment: share the code of what you have tried, the error logs of the issues you faced, etc

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am more interested in obtaining notifications in the future if my service stops polling for whatever reason.  how can i improve my OSB service or should I shift to bpel service and use on-alarm notification. or is there any other way I can monitor already existing DB polling service.